# Django Haystack Xapian: Default AND Chaining, among others, not working

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, xapian

Here is my haystack config:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'xapian_backend.XapianEngine',
        'PATH': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'xapian_index'),
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
        'BATCH_SIZE': 100,
    },
}
```

I'm using haystack's views.SearchView

All packages including Xapian updated to their latest version yesterday.

I'm searching a vegetables and locations index.
When I search for 'carrot California' (without quotes), I get results from all over the place, and different vegetables too. When I search for 'carrot and California', or 'carrot+California', the same thing happens. However, when I search for 'carrot AND California', I get the right results.

I manually set `HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR = 'AND'`, but that didn't work either.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

The larger question though is, what is the best/optimal configuration for Haystack+Xapian?

Comment: I've added this issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack/issues/129).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an [error](https://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack/issues/129) of Xapian-Haystack that was meanwhile [solved](https://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack/commit/a59e6963563f6b87915ae3f6526cc2a68989b7b2).

Comment: Installed the updated xapian-haystack from GitHub, Woks perfectly now.